# Code in Python works, but inside pyscript it get this error

Tags: python, html, sqlite, pyscript, sqlite3-python

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 435, in eval_code
> .run(globals, locals)
>
> File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 304, in run
> coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
>
> File "", line 3, in 
> File "/home/pyodide/connection_sqlite3.py", line 45, in returnGeral
> data = cursor.execute(r"SELECT * FROM tabela;")
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

A lot of the code in connection_sqlite3 needs work, it's just I don't understand where is the error comes from.

I try the Python code alone with a database, and it works, but when connected with html then this error appeared.

HTML markup:

```
type <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-config>
        [[fetch]]
        from = 'scripts/'
        files = ['connection_sqlite3.py'] 
    </py-config>
    <py-script src="scripts/main.py"></py-script>
    <div id="principal">
        <div id="navegation">
            <input placeholder="teste" type="text">
            <button py> search </button> 
        </div>
        <div id="table">

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html> here
```

`main.py` file

```
import connection_sqlite3 as sql

sql.returnGeral()
```

`connection_sqlite3.py` file

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

data = 'data/tutorial.db'

#query para criacao de tabelas
def templates(arquivo):
    raw = open(arquivo)
    edited = raw.read()
    return edited

#funcoes gerais

def connection():
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(data)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e}, and failed in the line 14")
    

def createTable(archive):
    try:
        conn = connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(archive)
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e}, error in the line 23")

def insertData(param):
    try:
        cursor = connection()
        cursor.execute(param)
        conn = connection()
        conn.commit()
        print(fr"{param} was inserted in the table" )
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e}, failed at line 41")

def returnGeral():
    try:
        connection()
        cursor = connection()
        data = cursor.execute(r"SELECT * FROM tabela;")
        raw = data.fetchall()
        for i in raw:
            print(i)
        return data
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e}, error in the line 34")
      
def execute(param):
    try:
        conn = connection(1)
        cursor = connection(2)
        cursor.execute(param)
        conn.commit()
        print(f'{param}, was executed successfully')
        
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e} error in line 64")
```

I was trying to create a database and link it with pyscrit to insert and return data in a web server, but for now it's just the local part.

Comment: Don't post errors as images.  Post all code, input/output, and errors as plain text.

Comment: ok, sorry, i ajusted the error, thank you

Comment: This line of code is failing `cursor = conn.cursor()`. Does the directory `data` exist in the browser's virtual file system? Remember that the virtual file system is recreated each time the page loads. I do not see your code creating that directory. Pyodide supports persistent mountable file systems. For a database, you probably want to use that.

Comment: this seens to be the problem, i transfer the database to the same folder as the html file, and it works, but one question, how do i add a folder to the virtual file system, you don't need to answer me if you don't want, you already help enough thank you.

Comment: The browser virtual file system is supported by the Python API. That is the file system used for Python file APIs unless you mount another file system to the virtual file system. Use  `os.mkdir()`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-directory-in-python/